# C# how to identify minified JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, minify

I'm simply reading a JavaScript file in a C# application and I need to know whether the JavaScript file is minified or not. 
The only way I could think of is to calculate the following ratio,

Minified Ratio = Number Of Newlines/FileSize

So in a non-minified file this value would be higher and in a minified file it would be smaller (probably less than 1).

Is there any better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on the minifier, you could look for certain signatures, e.g. `function(p,a,c,k,e,d)` or an `eval` around a large section

Comment: I think it's a correct approach. Typically minified code contains very few new lines. [Uglify2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2), for example, has a default `max-line-len` of 32K characters.

Answer (score 0):

UglifyJS2 has options like `--beautify` which retains new lines, correct approach will be to use regular expression as `Paul S` suggested or [JInt](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint)'s parser, [JavascriptParser.cs](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint/blob/master/Jint/Parser/JavascriptParser.cs).

Use regular expression to find `function\((?<var>([a-z][a-z0-9]*)(,|\)` and check if all var groups have very smaller length. Than you can check, total number of variables declared against length of variable.

If you want more advanced version, then you can use JInt's JavaScriptParser which gives Abstract Syntax Tree, in which you can identify following checks.

1. Is average function argument string length is less than 2 as all functions are defined as function(a,b,c)...
2. You encounter !0 or 1 instead of 'true' and !1 or 0 instead of false in boolean compare expressions.
3. Other common minified expressions such as eval around large section.